# How to customize the HTML code of Content Query Web Part

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-2010

I want to custom the output HTML code of CQWP and I do not want to see `<table class="s4-wpTopTable">...</table>`. But even I try to edit ContentQueryMain.xsl file by the help of this article:[Customizing the HTML code of a Content Query Web Part](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Customizing-the-HTML-code-of-a-Content-Query-Web-Part.aspx), the table is still there.I can't even find any code generated the table which class is "s4-wpTopTable".
So ,I need some talent guy to tell me how to stop the CQWP to generate TABLE.

I have tried to set the Content Query Webpart's SuppressWebPartChrome to "True",but the table is still there,  such a big problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to customize the output HTML of CQWP,you should:

1. Insure your CQWP is NOT in the webpartzone, because the webpartzone will make the the `SuppressWebPartChrome` does not work for your webpart.
2. Insert your webpart to the page with the help of SPD,and then in the code view,you can change the SuppressWebPartChrome of CQWP to `True`(Defualt is False).
3. Look at the source code of your page,the `<table class="s4-wpTopTable">...</table>` is not there now, cool!
4. Anyother addtionnal code generated by sharepoint of the CQWP,you can custom it in your ContentQueryMain.xsl file, so you should learn the language--XSTL .Don't be afraid of it,it is so easy for you to learn in one hour.

Answer (score 1):

I faced problems like you had and I decided to develop a web part that makes it easy to customize the look & feel of a portal. You can find detailed information about it here: [Item Lister Web Part](http://www.spwp.net/web-parts/item-lister-web-part.aspx)

Comment: But the CQWP has many advantages that your ListerWebPart hasn't . Do you know how to stop sharepoint to generated the table ?  It's some trouble for my partner to style the page cause the robus table! oops